# Jquery selecting input type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a login/register page, in which the forms switch depending on whether the user decide to login or register.

I'm trying to empty all of the `<input>` when the user switch forms.

I can get to erase all the contents of the `<input>` fields, but that's including the `<input type="submit">`, thus also erasing the submit button's message.

Here's what I tried to do to select every input except the submit one, but it doesn't empty the fields anymore :

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
      $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
      $(':text, :password, :email').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
      });
});
```

And here's what I tried before, selecting all input, also erasing the "submit" one :

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
      $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
      $('input').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
      });
});
```

Also, here's the html :

```
<div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" placeholder="nom" name="name_register"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="prenom" name="last_name_register"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="mot de passe" name="password_register"/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="adresse email" name="email_register"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Inscription"/>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#" class="register">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="email" placeholder="adresse email" name="email_login"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="mot de passe" name="password_login"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Connexion"/>
      <p class="message">Vous n'êtes pas enregistré? <a href="#" class="login">Créer un compte</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `input` tag for submit button, use `button` tag instead: `<button type="submit">Connexion</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input:not([type='submit'])").each
```

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You should use this selector:

```
$("input:not([type=submit])")
```

Comment: Use single quotes, your double quotes are escaping.

Answer (score 1):

User the following instead.

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
      $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
      $('input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email]').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$('.register-form')[0].reset();` it will reset form values

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your requirments correctly following will help you

```js
$('.message a').click(function() {
  $('form').animate({
    height: "toggle",
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, "slow");
  $('input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password]').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```